# How to use the drawRect method inside a for loop?

Tags: android, graphics, canvas, drawrect, ondraw

How can i draw a set of rectangles on a canvas Using DrawRect method? I am trying to generate a dynamic indoor map by just passing the coordinates of the blocks.

I want to know.. how to use the drawRect method inside a for loop..!

I made two classes by the help of Luke Taylor.(Thank you..! :) )

One is coordinate and the other one is main class called DrawMapActivity..
Now i need to know how to fill up the coordinates Array???

package itgsm.drawmap;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DrawMapActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

static Coordinates[] coordinates = new Coordinates[10]; // 10 is just an example

//    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//        setContentView(R.layout.main);
//     
//    }

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    Paint myPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(8/*1 /getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density*/);
    myPaint.setColor(0xffff0000);   //color.RED

    for(int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
        canvas.drawRect(new Rect(coordinates[i].getX(), coordinates[i].getY(),   coordinates[i].getX() + 10,coordinates[i].getY() + 10), myPaint); // 10 is the dimension of your block
        }


}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a method that takes an array of objects that contain coordinates:

This would be the class called "Coordinate" that contains the coordinates.

```
public class Coordinate {

int x;
int y;

public void setX(int x) {
this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
this.y = y;
}

public int getX() {
return this.x;
}

public int getY() {
return this.y;

}

}
```

You can create an array of these objects containing the individual coordinates:

```
Coordinates[] coordinates = new Coordinates[10]; // 10 is just an example
```

In your rendering method, you can now render the individual blocks.

```
public void drawMap(Coordinates[] coordinates) {
for(int i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
canvas.drawRect(new Rect(coordinates[i].getX, coordinates[i].getY, coordinates[i].getX + 10,coordinates[i].getY + 10), paint); // 10 is the dimension of your block
}
}
```

I hope this helps.

**Update:**

This is how you could fill one index of the array with an Coordinate object:

```
coordinates[1] = new Coordinate();
coordinates[1].setX(0);
coordinates[1].setY(0);
```

Comment: I made the classes you mentioned.. but im having a problem calling the drawRect method. Could you see the code above and help me out?

Comment: How can i fill the  Array??

static Coordinates[] coordinates = new Coordinates[10];

Comment: Your Coordinates array hasn't been filled with coordinates, here's a tutorial on arrays: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032744/how-to-open-a-new-intent-inside-ontouch-event

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class DrawDemo extends Activity {
DemoView demoview;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    demoview = new DemoView(this);
    setContentView(demoview);
}

private class DemoView extends View{
    public DemoView(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        // custom drawing code here
        // remember: y increases from top to bottom
        // x increases from left to right
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        // make the entire canvas white
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawPaint(paint);
        // another way to do this is to use:
        // canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

        // draw a solid green rectangle
        paint.setAntiAlias(false);
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
                     {
                    //make changes in arguments here
        canvas.drawRect(100, 5, 200, 30, paint);
                     }
                     }
                      }
                      }
```