# start activity is not working after changing to fragment

Tags: android, android-activity

i was having activity calls another ativity using `start activity`

i changed the second activity to fragment. and now i have exception when calling this fragment using `start activity`

help please.

```
Intent intentToOrder = new Intent(Food_Profile.this,
                            OrderMeal.class);
                    startActivity(intentToOrder);
```

notice please that `OrderMeal` is fragment

#### code

tv_orderMeal.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    // down
                    tv_orderMeal.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,
                            R.drawable.order_clicked, 0, 0);
                } else if ((event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    tv_orderMeal.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,
                            R.drawable.order, 0, 0);
                    Basket.setRestaurant(restaurant);
                    List<OrderFood> foodsToOrder = new LinkedList<OrderFood>();
                    OrderFood oneFoodOrder = new OrderFood();
                    oneFoodOrder.setRestaurantFood(restaurantFood);
                    oneFoodOrder.setNumber(1);
                    foodsToOrder.add(oneFoodOrder);
                    Basket.setFoods(foodsToOrder);
                    Intent intentToOrder = new Intent(Food_Profile.this,
                            OrderMeal.class);
                    startActivity(intentToOrder);
                    // up
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intentToOrder = new Intent(getActivity(),OrderMeal.class);
startActivity(intentToOrder);
```

Comment: Also your fragment class to extend Fragment not FragmentActivity

Comment: i can't use getactivity because i am calling in inside `OnTouchListener` that is why i was using the name of the class dot `this`

Comment: @user3110137, I think I need to see some code, you are doing some stuff wrong. Both of your questions are related and I think there is a better way to solve it all together

Comment: @user3110137, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12032744/how-to-open-a-new-intent-inside-ontouch-event

Comment: i gave you the whole code, please check it in the edited question,

Comment: @user3110137, try solution in last link I gave you

Comment: there is no solution in that link, please check it again. but don't worry, i found the solution, it is hard to descripe, but if u want i will tell